# Function that to look up then perform task

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a short script that looks to see if a class or id is present in then document. If it is then do the following:

```
$(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
$(this).addClass("tab_item_color");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property on a jQuery object. For example:

```
if( $('.your-class').length )
{
    $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
}
```

The `if()` block will only execute if there is an element in the DOM which has a class of `your-class`.

Comment: Thank you, what does length do?

Comment: @david It returns the number of elements in the jQuery collection.

Comment: but does NOT print number found to the output of the webpage?

Comment: If you wish to do that, it's possible, but just calling `length` will return it for use.

Comment: Still not swapping the class

Comment: Yes. Must be inside $(function() { });

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
$(function() { 
    if ($('.yourClassName').length){
        $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color").addClass("YourNewClassName"); //It will swap your class.                          
    }
});
```

For more information you can also visit [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: `exists()`? Do you have documentation for that?

Comment: No, it doesn't... `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).exists is not a function`: https://jsfiddle.net/6dat8v3a/

Comment: first way doesnt appear to swap the class

Comment: `code` if( $('.headerSpecialTrigger').length)
{
 $('.extmenubar').removeClass('.headerSpecial');
}`code`

Comment: Can this be run standalone function? i can open the statement with "if". does not work for me.

Comment: $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color").addClass("tab_item_color"); - script will remove .tab_item then does ?what? with "tab_item_color" then swaps with "tab_item_color"

Comment: sorry im trying to understand as it still isnt working.

Comment: how can i accept something when there is now 3 separate classes involved, so my question and my example of what im doing is valid

Comment: i thought "tab_item_new" was my "YourNEwClassName"

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by checking the first object that is returned from  jquery. For-example

```
if ($(".your-class")[0]){
     $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
 }
```

Comment: .tab_item will be removed and replaced with tab_item_color?

Comment: You can add another alternative such as `else{` statement

Comment: Am not really sure in which situation are you performing this action.

Comment: I want the "header" to be "position:fixed" but only when a page contains a certain class (class is just for a reference point) to be swapped, so on those pages the header is fixed and on other it is not.

Comment: Means i can keep everything as " include" pages for my template system without having to create a whole separate file just for one line of css that is different.